# Make shortcuts to directories via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, alias

My problem is: whenever I'm coding, I work inside folders that are inside other folders and it's a long way to type:

```
cd /folder1/folder2/.../folderN
```

I know it's possible to make a shortcut to the folder using `alias`. So it would be:

```
alias ep="cd /Users/thi/Dropbox/CurrentProject"
```

My question is, where should I put this alias? Inside `/etc/bashrc`? Or should I create a file called `~/.profile` and place it there? Where should I put it?

Comment: I think what would take you to the next level is learning about shell completion. bash's completion is pretty basic, but zsh has extensible completion. For example `ls -l P/H/O/Cla<tab>` expands to `ls -l Projects/Home/OpenGL/Clams`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I keep aliases in `~/.bash_profile`.

Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells by default. When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, it reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`. The terminal emulators on other platforms often open new shells as non-login shells, so for example bash reads `~/.bashrc` but not `~/.bash_profile`. OS X users often use `~/.bash_profile` as the personal configuration file corresponding to `~/.bashrc` on other platforms, but it is also possible to source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` or to tell Terminal or iTerm 2 to open new shells as non-login shells.

If both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` exist, bash only reads `~/.bash_profile` when it is invoked as an interactive login shell. `~/.profile` is also used by other shells and programs that might not understand the same configuration options as bash.

`/etc/bashrc` is owned by root, and it might get replaced when you upgrade OS X.

See `man bash|less +^INVOCATION` or https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you put alias definitions into the same file as your `$PATH` definitions which is probably `~/.bashrc`.

---

Technically speaking an alias is not a shortcut to a folder but for any shell command. So you can also have things like

```
alias heal='xattr -d com.apple.quarantine'
alias la='ls -lFa'
alias ll='ls -lF'
alias ls='ls -FG'
alias show-path='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'
```

to make your life easier. Aliases are replaced as-is by the shell so if you run

```
heal downloadedFile.dmg
```

it gets expanded to

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine downloadedFile.dmg
```

and executed afterwards. If you need more flexibility with parameters you may want to look into shell functions (but that probably should go into another question).

Answer (score 1):

i am not expert in bash but i think you should put your alias inside .bashrc in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

## The short answer is: *(generally)*

Add it to `~/.bash_profile`

```
echo 'alias ep="cd $HOME/Dropbox/CurrentProject"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

***NOTE:*** *There shouldn't be any space between the alias/variable and the **equals sign ("=")** and the value. If your value has spaces then the whole value should be put in quotes.*

## A better answer is: *(probably)*

Try setting an environment variable, instead. This is probably more like what you actually want.

```
echo 'export EP="$HOME/Dropbox/CurrentProject"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'alias ep="cd $EP"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

***NOTE:*** *That environment variables are accessed by prepending the **dollar sign ("$")**. However, when being defined, the **dollar sign ("$")** should be omitted.*

## An alternative answer is: *(possibly)*

***Symbolic-Links***. *AKA.* ***Symlinks***. *{FKA. **Aliases**. (Mac OS)}.* *{BKA. **Shortcuts**. (Windows OS)}.*

```
ln -s <dirA/subB/fileC_in> <dirX/subY/symbZ_out>
```

***NOTE:*** *symlinks are sometimes denoted by prepending the **ampersand sign ("@")**.*

Comment: Please see [the site chat channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) if you want to discuss the lock on this post and future edits.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/789465) neatly summarises what ideally belongs in each of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bash_profile`. In summary:

- ~/.bash_profile should be super-simple and just load .profile and
  .bashrc (in that order)
- ~/.profile has the stuff NOT specifically related to bash, such as
  environment variables (PATH and friends)
- ~/.bashrc has anything you'd want at an interactive command line.
  Command prompt, EDITOR variable, bash aliases for my use

  A few other notes:
- Anything that should be available to graphical applications OR to sh
  (or bash invoked as sh) MUST be in ~/.profile
- ~/.bashrc must not output anything
- Anything that should be available only to login shells should go in
  ~/.profile
- Ensure that ~/.bash_login does not exist.